# redirect sh script output to two logs, one with -x and one without

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to run a script once and have it write to two logs.  One log will be detailed and will have the output of -x option.  The other log will not be detailed and will have just the regular output without the -x option?

Comment: You can write a function, based on some boolean, which will do the logging. What do you even mean by `-x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set -x` has this wonderful thing where it's output is actually not printed to `stdout` but rather to `stderr`.

Thus if you have

```
myscript.bash 1> log 2> xlog
```

with `set -x` in the script, so `log` contains your regular output and `xlog` the output of the debugging commands, `+ <cmd>`, and the errors.

If you want a file containing all output, and one just regular output this may be more difficult, and I think will require editing the log at the end. Here is a wrapper script accepting another script to run:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
. $1 &> full.log
set +x
sed '/^+.*/d' full.log > out.log
```

where you call

```
wrap.sh myscript.sh
```

This has the disadvantage that any line starting with `+` is deleted, which may or may not be enough. There may be a better solution with process substitution but I cannot think of one that preserves the order between `stdout` and `stderr`.